# Escape character not working in wordpress php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code as following:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
        <?php 
        if( of_get_option( 'logo', true ) != '' ) { 
            if( of_get_option('logo', true) == "http://1"){
                echo "<h1>".__('Logo','nature-one')."</h1>";
            } else {
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( of_get_option( 'logo', true )); ?>" / >
        <?php } } else { ?>
            <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
            <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </a>
</div><!-- logo -->
```

Which produces following output:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="https://shuklaphanta-jungle-resort-shiwasreet.c9users.io/">
<h1>Shuklaphanta Jungle Cottage</h1>
    Your Gateway to Shuklaphanta Wildlife Reserve                                                                  </a>
</div>
```

I cannot do escape character work.
How do I produce?

```
<h1 id="header-logo-h1>Something here</h1>
```

as html?

Comment: Can you format your code so that it's readable, please?

Comment: @IarsAnders.. You mean, like moving the code **further** to the right, so there's more of that lovely blue space, less interrupted by code?

Comment: @spencer7593 I had never noticed how nice that blue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any escaping. Just change this line:

```
        <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
```

to:

```
        <h1 id="header-logo-h1"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
echo '<h1 id="header-logo-h1">'.$text.'</h1>';
```

Or escape the double quotes:

```
echo "<h1 id=\"header-logo-h1\">".$text."</h1>";
```

Comment: he's not using `echo` statements for his HTML, he's returning to raw text output mode in the script with `?>`. So no escape characters are needed.